# Iframe with Cypress: How to wait api call inside iframe

Tags: iframe, cypress

I'm using Cypress to test behavior inside iFrame

A request to server side is done inside the iFrame,
My test should wait for the request to be done and continue the test

currently I'm waiting the api call to be finished by:

```
 cy.route("POST", "URL")).as("Alias");
 cy.wait("@Alias");
```

Api is being called successfully, but in Cypress it failed with timeout waiting for the API to be called.

Comment: Did u finally find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same slightly different problem.
I advise you to enter in an iframe this piece of code that you will modify to your sauce :

`cy.get('iframe').then((iframe) => {
    const body = iframe.contents().find('body');
    cy.wrap(body).find('a').click();
});`

I found the solution [here](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/136)

And for your API wait problem you can use cy.wait()

`cy.wait(time)`

[Doc](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/wait.html#Syntax)